# Java.util.Timer stops counting if machine enters a Sleep mode

Tags: java, javafx, timertask

I'm using `java.util.TimerTask` to switch scene after certain period of time in JavaFX application. I've noticed that if machine enters a sleep mode - timer stops counting. How can this be fixed ? Is this made by design ?

Comment: When the machine is in sleep mode nothing runs, there is nothing you can do to change this. It's the same as asking how to continue running the code when the computer is turned off.

Comment: You can only prevent the system from entering sleep mode.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, what platform are you on? On Ubuntu 14.04 (in a VM) and I find any missed firings are fired when the computer wakes.

Comment: @FrankWilson I'm on MacOS Sierra. Also tested on El Capitano.